# Is a book fund related to money?

Tags: meaning

dictionary ([britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/fund)):

> one of the meanings of "*fund*":
> *a fund - an amount of money that is used for a special purpose*

> one of examples for this definition:
> **(1)** *the library's book fund*

To me, (1) is the aggregate of all books in the library.
But according to the definition, (1) has something to do with money rather than books.

Could you please explain to me :
What does (1) mean?
How is (1) related to the dictionary definition?

Comment: Normally 'XXX fund' means 'money to be used to buy, rent, hire, etc, XXX'.

Comment: A useful (for something) collection of XXXs might be 'a fund of XXXs'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, a library's *book fund* would be an amount of money the library has that is designated for buying books.

Comment: Yes, and I would call the totality or aggregate of a library's books its 'stock'.